# Modifications of raster extent and resolution change the total sum of pixel values

Tags: r, resolution, raster, r-raster, extent

I wish to change the resolution and extent of a raster. I have tried to combine in different ways extend, aggregate, resample but unsuccessfully… below is a code I wrote to get the right resolution and extent, but as a consequence, the total pixel values are changed (and the difference can be quite large in some cases...). There are quite a lot on posts online on raster extents and resolutions, but I haven't managed to solve my problem. Is there a way I can change the resolution and extent while minimizing changes in total pixel values (cellStats(r, sum))? Thank you very much.

```
library(raster)

#sample rasters
r <- raster(extent(-180,179.9999, -55.91668 , 83.58326))
res(r)<-c(0.5/6, 0.5/6)
r <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
cellStats(r, sum) #3615229

temp_extent <- raster(extent(-180,180, -90 , 90))
res(temp_extent)<-c(0.5, 0.5)

# to get resolution (0.5, 0.5)
r1 <- aggregate(r, fact=6, fun=sum)
cellStats(r1, sum) #3615229
r1
# to get extent (-180,180,-90,90)
r2 <- resample(x= r1, y=temp_extent, method="bilinear") # what I am hoping is for NA to fill the added pixels
cellStats(r2, sum) #problem: gives different total value: 3615916
r2
```

Comment: If you resample, you will necessarily change the pixel values, right?

Comment: @bdemarest thanks, I have edited my question. I wonder whether there is a way I can change both extent and resolution while minimizing changes in cellStats(r, sum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Nearest Neighbour resampling in the last passage should do the trick:

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp

#sample rasters
r <- raster(extent(-180,179.9999, -55.91668 , 83.58326))
res(r)<-c(0.5/6, 0.5/6)
set.seed(1234)
r <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
cellStats(r, sum)
#> [1] 3615109

temp_extent <- raster(extent(-180,180, -90 , 90))
res(temp_extent)<-c(0.5, 0.5)

# to get resolution (0.5, 0.5)
r1 <- aggregate(r, fact=6, fun=sum)
cellStats(r1, sum)
#> [1] 3615109

# to get extent (-180,180,-90,90)
r2 <- resample(x= r1, y=temp_extent, method="ngb") 
cellStats(r2, sum)
#> [1] 3615109

all.equal(cellStats(r, sum), cellStats(r2, sum))
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Ibusett. I thought I shouldn't use ngb for non categorical variables... but indeed it works! Thanks